# it is required to add an overgrip on a Fischer sorb tack

Tags: equipment, tennis

Recently, I have bought a Fischer racket ( it doesn't matter which type ).

It has a very nice sorb tack ( like a grip ), very firm, really nice to be touch.

I was wondering if it is necessary to buy some overgrips to put over this sorb tack?

Will it reduce the firmness of the sorb tack? Will it offer me some advantages?

Answer (score 1):

If you like the way the current grip feels - there is no need to put any overgrip on top of the grip. Overgrips generally just improve tackiness, absorb moisture (sweat) and preserve the condition of the replacement grip - but they are not necessary or a requirement for playing with the racquet. You could experiement by trying out an overgrip you like and then take it off if you don't feel like it improves the feel of the grip. Overgrips are usually available to buy in packs of 3 and fairly inexpensive - $5-10 USD or so.